# Generated Hyperlink disappears when entering new Private Sub

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

In the attached code, I am searching for a keyword, then creating a new sheet with row entries like file name, sheet, cell, data.  I am attempting to put in a hyperlink (thanks to [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout))  to the found keyword in just the "cell" column (i.e. column "C" in this program).  The hyperlink created disappears when going into the new `Private Sub` which is where I extract the row data from the searched workbook resulting in the newly created file not containing any hyperlinks.  Can you help me maintain the hyperlinks in the newly created file?  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As String
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xStrSearch = "failed"
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  ' Create the report sheet at first position then name it "Summary"
  Dim wsReport As Worksheet, rCellwsReport As Range
  Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
  wsReport.Name = "Summary"
  Set rCellwsReport = wsReport.Cells(2, 2)
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = wsReport
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Test"
        .Cells(xRow, 5) = "Limit Low"
        .Cells(xRow, 6) = "Limit High"
        .Cells(xRow, 7) = "Measured"
        .Cells(xRow, 8) = "Unit"
        .Cells(xRow, 9) = "Status"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsx")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        shName = xWk.Name
                        If InStr(1, shName, " ") Then shName = "'" & shName & "'"
                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        Range("C" & xRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & _
                                              xWb.FullName & _
                                              "]" & _
                                              shName & _
                                              "!" & _
                                              xFound.Address & _
                                              Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & _
                                              xFound.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
                        WriteDetails rCellwsReport, xFound

                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Range("A1:A" & xCount + 1).Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With

    MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "SUPERtools for Excel"
ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    Set xWk = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xFld = Nothing
    Set xFso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef xReceiver As Range, ByRef xDonor As Range)
  xReceiver.Value = xDonor.Parent.Name

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  ' Copy the row of the Donor to the receiver starting from column D.
  ' Since you want to preserve formats, we use the .Copy method
    xDonor.EntireRow.Resize(, 100).Copy xReceiver.Offset(, 2)
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set xReceiver = xReceiver.Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You could save the hyperlink as a constant, outside of the sub-routines, or you could have the second sub-routine run from within the first sub-routine (nest it).  Or, you could have one large sub-routine that encompasses all items.  Just a few ideas that come to mind.

Comment: @Cyril, can you give me an example of the easiest approach?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you want cell Summary!C2 to contain?  You first set it to the address of the cell containing "failed" (using the line `.Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address`), then you immediately change it to be a formula (using the line `Range("C" & xRow).Formula = ...` [and you should really have a `.` before `Range`]), then you call your subroutine to set it back to the address of the cell containing "failed" again (using the line `xReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = xDonor.Address`)

Comment: @YowE3K, made a modification based on your input by deleting the `xReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = xDonor.Address`.  Now, when I run the code, I only get the first 6 hyperlinks showing.  I do not get any after the 8 row in the newly created sheet.

Comment: That's probably because you are writing the hyperlink formula to the active sheet (which might be in a different workbook).  You really should put that `.` before `Range` unless you are trying to place the hyperlink in the workbooks you are searching through.  (But, if so, why close the workbook without saving?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, qualify your `Range` statement so that it does not place the hyperlink in the workbook that you then close without saving.

I.e. change

```
Range("C" & xRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & _
```

to

```
.Range("C" & xRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & _
```

---

Taking the relevant lines from your code:

```
'******************************************
'*** Set xOut so that it refers to wsReport
Set xOut = wsReport
'******************************************

xRow = 1

'******************************************
'*** Begin a With block so that "." means "xOut."
With xOut
'******************************************

    .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Test"
    .Cells(xRow, 5) = "Limit Low"
    .Cells(xRow, 6) = "Limit High"
    .Cells(xRow, 7) = "Measured"
    .Cells(xRow, 8) = "Unit"
    .Cells(xRow, 9) = "Status"
    Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
    xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While xStrFile <> ""

'******************************************
'*** Open a workbook, and make it the ActiveWorkbook and one of its sheets
'*** the ActiveSheet
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)        
'******************************************

        For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
            Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                xStrAddress = xFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If xFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    shName = xWk.Name
                    If InStr(1, shName, " ") Then shName = "'" & shName & "'"
                    xCount = xCount + 1
                    xRow = xRow + 1

'******************************************
'*** Write information to column A of the report
                    .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
'******************************************

'******************************************
'*** Write information to column B of the report
                    .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
'******************************************

'******************************************
'*** Write information to column C of the report
                    .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
'******************************************

'******************************************
'*** Write information to column C of the ActiveWorkbook's ActiveSheet
'*** (because "Range" is unqualified)
'*** If this was ".Range" it would write information to column C of the report
                    Range("C" & xRow).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & _
                                                  xWb.FullName & _
                                                  "]" & _
                                                  shName & _
                                                  "!" & _
                                                  xFound.Address & _
                                                  Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & _
                                                  xFound.Address & Chr(34) & ")"
'******************************************

                    WriteDetails rCellwsReport, xFound

                End If
                Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
            Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
        Next

'******************************************
'*** Close the ActiveWorkbook (which has had hyperlinks added to it)
'*** without saving
        xWb.Close (False)
'******************************************
```

---

An "official" (and possibly "credible") source for my telling you to qualify the `Range` can be found in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) for the `Range` object, which says (in part):

> When it’s used without an object qualifier (an object to the left of the period), the Range property returns a range on the active sheet.